# How to get rid of non-null assertion

Tags: typescript

I am very new to Typescript so please bear with me if this question is too basic.

I am destructuring an object like this

```
const {
firstName,
lastName,
} = human!;
```

When I remove the ! I get a type error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, the non-null assertion operator (!) is used to tell the compiler that a value will not be null or undefined. It allows you to override TypeScript's type checking and assert that a variable or property will have a non-null value at runtime.

see the below example

```
function greet(name: string | null): string {
 // Use the non-null assertion operator to assert that 'name' is not null
 return `Hello, ${name!.toUpperCase()}!`;
}

console.log(greet("Alice"));      // Output: Hello, ALICE!
console.log(greet(null));         // Output: Error - Runtime exception
```

please check whether the `human` object contains valid values. if so you could remove the non-null assertion

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few solutions I could think of right now. Choose either of the following:

1. Check first if `human` is not null nor undefined before destructuring.

   ```ts
   if(human) {
     const { firstName, lastName } = human;
   }
   ```
2. Use the variable `human` for destructuring *if* it's set. Otherwise, use a mock object that sets `firstName` and `lastName` to `null` (or anything you want) when destructured.

   ```ts
   const { firstName, lastName } = human ?? { null, null };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { firstName, lastName } = human ?? {}
```

This destructures `human` if it's defined, otherwise an empty object. Both `firstName` and `lastName` will have the type `string | undefined`, assuming they are defined in `human` but always undefined in `{}`.

Another common strategy is to use early return.

```
if (!human) {
  return
};

const { firstName, lastName } = human; // now guaranteed to be defined
```